# Mongoose _id affected before saving

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });

var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
console.log(kitty);
kitty.save();
console.log(kitty);
```

this output:

`{ name: 'Zildjian', _id: 523194d562b0455801000001 }` twice

I've tried by delaying the save after a timeout, but it's the same, which points to the _id being set on the `new Cat` and not the `.save()`

Is this because of mongodb or mongoose, why is the _id set before the actual persistence?

Comment: Have you looked at the IDs available from `Cat.find().exec(function(err,docs){console.log(docs);});`?

Comment: My guess is that it autogenerates id's so that you do not have to do a roundtrip to the server to find out what the id turned out to be.

Comment: Yes that's convenient, especially for testing, but it surprised me at first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most MongoDb drivers will automatically generate the ObjectId/`_id` client side, including the native driver for Node.js. There's a tiny amount of locking that occurs to generate an ID uniquely, so there's little reason to not distribute the generation to connected clients.

Mongoose needs a unique identifier to track and reference objects, so it creates an identifier immediately.

In the Node.JS client you can [optionally](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html) set for example the property `forceServerObjectId` to `true` to control this behavior.

However, this cannot be overridden when using Mongoose per the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html):

> Mongoose forces the db option forceServerObjectId false and cannot be
>   overridden. Mongoose defaults the server auto_reconnect options to
>   true which can be overridden. See the node-mongodb-native driver
>   instance for options that it understands.

Comment: What happens if two clients generate the same id and tell mongo to save it? (I know I know, UUIDs are very unlikely to collide)

Comment: The second would just save over the other/first one.It's not actually a UUID and and in a typical environment, it shouldn't conflict with other servers generating `_id`s.