# Mongoose - How to prevent mongoose from creating _id on model instantiation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want MongoDB itself to add an _id upon insertion so I can track the insertion time using the ObjectID but when I do `new MyModel(...)`, moongose will add the id field.

How do I prevent this so the db itself adds the id?

Alternatively how do I create a field which will be set to the INSERTION time by the db?

Edit: I see that this is not technically possible with mongoose, so would it be possible to add a field that is set by MongoDB when the insertion is done?

My model (if relevant):

```
{
  timestamp: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  signaler: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  source: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    trim: true
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    trim: true
  },
  key: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  level: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    trim: true,
    uppercase: true,
    enum: ['ALARM', 'WARNING', 'NORMAL']
  },
  payload: {
    type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    required: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between letting mongo do it vs mongoose?

Comment: I might do `new MyModel()` and then call `model.save()` much later, thus the id will not actually be tracking the insertion time, also there would be a slight time difference between me calling save() and the document actually being inserted.

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18762482/1259510), the `forceServerObjectId` connection option that controls this is forced to false by Mongoose, and can't be overridden. I'd provide a link to the current docs, but they don't mention it anymore.

Comment: Can you post your model?

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting use case you have.  Mongoose really does create that _id on when you call a  Model constructor!

I see three paths forward:

1. Don't use mongoose.  The lower level mongo driver doesn't create  _ids util you insert into a collection.
2. Pass around a plain javascript object until you are ready to save
           it, then use the Model.create method.
3. Finally, you can use the pre save middleware to update the _id, by manually generating a new one (with  mongoose.Types.ObjectId()) that will have more accurate time info.

If you want to introduce a createdAt field that is updated when the document is inserted, then you are also going handle the pre save middleware. That's the way this popular plugin does it: https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-timestamp/blob/master/index.js

Comment: I guess the 2nd option seems the best, what if I let mongoose generate the id the way it wants but add another field whose value is set at insertion time by the db? (have updated question to reflect this)